# Creating a transparent arrow above image in CSS3

Tags: html, css, less, css-shapes

I'm trying to create an effect where I have a transparent arrow above any image in CSS3. See the following image.

[image: Transparent arrow aboev image]

Any ideas how to do this effect? Using LESS if that comes to any help.

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-css-arrow-triangle-over-an-image

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### To draw a transparent / inverted triangle in CSS3

you could use the [CSS3 triangle technic](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/#triangle-left), and make the inverted shape by combining the `:before` and `:after` pseudo objects, each to draw one part of the triangle.

You could do something like this:

```
.image {
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:340px;
    background:orange;
}
.image:before, .image:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:0;
    border-left:20px solid white;
    left:0;
}
.image:before {
    top:0;
    height:20px;
    border-bottom:16px solid transparent;
}
.image:after {
    top:36px;
    bottom:0;
    border-top:16px solid transparent;
}
```

here is an illustrative [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DEdGU/)

I just used a plane orange background for the example ... but you can change it to image, and you hopefully get what you wanted =)

---

**Edit:** and a more final result could then be something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DEdGU/2/)

Comment: and here is the same example but using an image: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DEdGU/1/)

Comment: It doesn't work if your body has background image though

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like this:

```
.arrow {
    bottom: -25px; 
    left: 30px; 
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.arrow:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    background: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: -19px;
    left: 3px;
    background: #999;
    border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```