# CSS speech bubble with full background image

Tags: css, background-image

I know it's quite easy to simply add a small triangle to the bottom of an element, but I want the background image to extend into the triangle. How could I achieve this?

Comment: he knows how to make a speech bubble and adding a triangle, but he also wants the arrow to have background image used for speech buuble

Comment: @Mr.Alien You can make elements look like speech bubbles by adding rounded corners and an extra element or pseudo-element to make the triangle, but I need the background image of the bubble to extend into the triangle.

Comment: @Bobe Where's the code/demo?

Comment: if you're after doing speech bubbles through pure css (no images) [this is pretty good site](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/)

Comment: This is a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-css-arrow-triangle

Answer (score 5):

Here I just answered something like this yesterday: [Creating a transparent arrow above image in CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540274/creating-a-transparent-arrow-above-image-in-css3/16541243#16541243)

But for having the triangle on the bottom, you would do something like this:

```
.image {
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:340px;
    background:orange;
}
.image:before, .image:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    height:0;
    border-bottom:20px solid white;
    bottom:0;
}
.image:before {
    left:0;
    width:20px;
    border-right:16px solid transparent;
}
.image:after {
    left:36px;
    right:0;
    border-left:16px solid transparent;
}
```

and a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DEdGU/6/)

For something fancier you could also use [masking](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/) and `clip-path`.