# how to add picture in the background of a CSS triangle

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

[image: Like this]

I've tried but so far i have made without any background using css border hack. How to advance it with an image like the the picture above?

Comment: Can't you just inspect element?

Comment: this has been asked before see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-arrow-triangle/23759602#23759602) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540274/creating-a-transparent-arrow-above-image-in-css3?lq=1) ...

Comment: i did @Justinas but cant find out about how the image is placed image

Comment: This question wasn't an exact duplicate as the triangle is over other content and it needs to be seen. I added a solution for this situation in my answer here : [transparent arrow/triangle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-arrow-triangle/23759602#23759602)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CSS triangle generator](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/) and fix it.

```
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 100px 100px 100px;
border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent
```

See also [Creating a transparent arrow above image in CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540274/creating-a-transparent-arrow-above-image-in-css3/16541243#16541243)